# The cohomology ring of the Klein bottle with respect to any ring

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology

Let $K$ be the Klein bottle and $R$ be a commutative unitary ring. How many cohomology rings $H^\ast(K; R)$ are known? Is there any reference to look up a specific value? A computer program able to compute them?

I want to point out: I am (in principle) able to do this computations on my own, I am not asking for help with homework or something, but I am looking for a ring such that $H^\ast(K; R)$ has some specific properties, hence I could use something like a comparative table of values of $H^\ast(K; R)$. Has anyone any suggestion?

Comment: I dont get it, doesnt the universal coefficients  theorem give you what you need ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus How? I'm interested in the ring structure of $H^\ast(K; R)$

Comment: If you work out the cases where $R$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ a prime (in two cases, $p=2$ and $p$ odd), you'll have pretty much covered the bases.

Comment: You can calculate this explicitly using the standard $\Delta$-complex structure on the Klein bottle. It's not much more difficult for arbitrary rings than it is in the usual cases, the result simply doesn't look as nice. Have you tried this?